# How does 'call' work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, call

I have a question on 'call' in javascript.

```
var humanWithHand = function(){
    this.raiseHand = function(){
        alert("raise hand");
    }
}

var humanWithFoot = function(){
    this.raiseFoot = function(){
        alert("raise foot");
    }
}

var human = function(){

    humanWithHand.call( this );
    humanWithFoot.call( this );

}

var test = new human();
```

so..when I use 'call' as humanWithHand.call(this), what happens internally?

does humanWithHand variable copies (or points?) its properties and members to human variable's prototype?

Comment: [MDN Documentation call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.call()` sets the `this` value and then calls the function with the arguments you passed to `.call()`.  You use `.call()` instead of just calling the function directly when you want to set the `this` value inside the called function rather than let it be set to whatever javascript would normally set it to.

`.apply()` is a sister function.  It can also set the `this` value and it can take arguments in an array so it can be used when you are trying to pass a variable argument list from some other function call or when you're constructing an argument list programmatically which may have different numbers of arguments depending upon the situation.

Answer (score 11):

Yehuda Katz has [a good writeup](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) of JavaScript's `Function#call` method. His writeup should answer your question, and many followup questions besides.

When you call a function directly, using the general syntax:

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log("foo");
  return this;
};
foo(); // evaluates to `window`
```

Then `this` inside the function call is whatever `this` is outside the function call. By default, in the browser, `this` outside any function calls is `window`. So inside the function call as above, `this` is also by default `window`.

When you call a function using the method-call syntax:

```
var bar = {
  foo: function() {
    console.log("foo");
    return this;
  }
};
bar.foo(); // evaluates to `bar`
```

Then `this` inside the function call is the object to the left of the rightmost period: in this case, `bar`.

We can simulate this situation using `call`.

When you set up a function outside an object and want to call it with `this` inside the function call set to an object, you can:

```
var foo = function() {
  console.log("foo");
  return this;
}
var bar = { };
foo.call(bar); // evaluates to `bar`
```

You can use this technique to pass arguments as well:

```
var foo = function(arg1, arg2) {
  console.log("foo");
  return arg1 + arg2;
}
var bar = { };
foo.call(bar, "abc", "xyz"); // evaluates to `"abcxyz"`
```

Comment: Great Explanation