# How does the jQuery .each() function export the index as a usable variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok so the jQuery .each() function has a really handy feature where if you write something like this:

```
$('.element').each(function(index){
    console.log(index);
});
```

You have access to the index of whatever the currently selected element is through the "index" variable.

.each() is essentially exporting a usable variable into the function that it is holding.

My question is how does jQuery do that?

I really want to know so that I can use that functionality in my own custom code.

**Update**

The question isn't "how does .each()" work. My question is more of a "how does javascript work" and I'm just using the jQuery .each() function as an easy example to get across what I'm trying to ask for without having to write a long winded explanation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187156/jquery-each-how-does-it-work-really-internally

Comment: `for(i=0; i<3; i++){ /*Here you got access to i as well*/ }`

Comment: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js   Raw Source Code.

Comment: See the jQuery source code for this function here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/bb026fc12c3c2ad37f47f0919e484bddcdc3d291/src/core.js#L270

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply passes the loop variable to the callback. Something like

```
function forEach(callback) {
  // elements comes from somewhere somehow 
  for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    callback.call(elements[i], i, elements[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: those interested can view the actual source at http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.each, specifically, the last else block for the use case in the OPs questions

Comment: The bit that I was getting confused over was was the stuff inside the .call() brackets. For those that are also confused about .call(), the first parameter sets what "this" becomes inside the callback function. Every parameter after that is essentially a variable that is able to be accessed from inside the callback function.

Comment: More references: [How does 'call' work in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7265607/218196), https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call . The example could have also been written as `callback(i, elements[i])`, but jQuery also sets `this` explicitly, hence the use of `.call`.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because it's a callback function, you can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Declaring_and_Using_Callbacks) and [here](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/).

For the callback in the `.each()` specifically, you can refer to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/each/) where it says:

> The .each() method is designed to make DOM looping constructs concise
>   and less error-prone. When called it iterates over the DOM elements
>   that are part of the jQuery object. Each time the callback runs, it is
>   passed the current loop iteration, beginning from 0. More importantly,
>   the callback is fired in the context of the current DOM element, so
>   the keyword this refers to the element.

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery.each( array, callback )**

array
Type: Array
The array to iterate over.

callback
Type: Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )
The function that will be executed on every object.

here is code part in http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js (it's same also in: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js) :

```
each: function( obj, callback, args ) {
        var value,
            i = 0,
            length = obj.length,
            isArray = isArraylike( obj );

        if ( args ) {
            if ( isArray ) {
                for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                    value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for ( i in obj ) {
                    value = callback.apply( obj[ i ], args );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

        // A special, fast, case for the most common use of each
        } else {
            if ( isArray ) {
                for ( ; i < length; i++ ) {
                    value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                for ( i in obj ) {
                    value = callback.call( obj[ i ], i, obj[ i ] );

                    if ( value === false ) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    },
```

Comment: The OP already knows that. The question has a simple example. That's not what he's asking.