# Reconfigure DOM not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a couple children (not a fixed amount) in a `div`. There is a `text input` that lets the user type in a number.

Then there's a `function organizeNumberOfRows` which organizes the children based on the number from the `input`. Let me give an example. Let's say I have 4 children, and the `text input` has a number of 3. `organizeNumberOfRows` will create a `div` for every 3 children and add it to the parent element.

The outcome hierarchy for:

- 4 children, `input` 3: `#parentElem > .innerWrapper > (.child * 3) + .innerWrapper > .child`
- 4 children, `input` 2: `#parentElem > .innerWrapper > (.child * 2) + .innerWrapper > (.child * 2)`

Hope this is clear.

Every time the `text input` changes, I'm going to have to reconfigure the dom. The way I did it is (`function clearTiles`), I add all the child elements to a `var` which is a `div`, and then call `organizeNumberOfRows`.

When I call `organizeNumberOfRows` (after I change the `textInput`), nothing happens. How can I reconfigure the children after a number was inserted in the `text input`?

#### JSFiddle

```js
var parentTileElement = document.getElementById('parentTileElement'),
  amountOfRowsInput = document.getElementById('amountOfRows');

function NumberOfRows( /** Int */ defaultValue) {
  var value = defaultValue;

  this.set = function(val) {
    value = val;
    var parent = clearTiles();
    console.log(parent, val);
    organizeNumberOfRows(val, parent);
  };
  this.get = function() {
    return parseInt(value);
  }
}
var _numberOfRows = new NumberOfRows(3);
var _outerTilesWrapper = document.createElement('div');
var _innerTilesWrapper;

amountOfRows.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  _numberOfRows.set(this.value);
});

organizeNumberOfRows(_numberOfRows.get(), parentTileElement);

function organizeNumberOfRows( /** Int */ numberOfRows, /** DOM Element */ parentElem) {
  while (parentElem.children.length) {
    var currentTile = parentElem.children[0];
    if (typeof _innerTilesWrapper === 'undefined' || _innerTilesWrapper.children.length === numberOfRows) {
      _innerTilesWrapper = document.createElement('div');
      _innerTilesWrapper.className = 'innerWrapper';
      _outerTilesWrapper.appendChild(_innerTilesWrapper);
    }
    _innerTilesWrapper.appendChild(currentTile);
  }
  parentTileElement.appendChild(_outerTilesWrapper);
}

function clearTiles() {
  var tempDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var innerTileWrappers = parentTileElement.firstElementChild.children;

  while (innerTileWrappers.length) {
    while (innerTileWrappers[0].children.length) {
      tempDiv.appendChild(innerTileWrappers[0].children[0]);
    }
    parentTileElement.firstElementChild.removeChild(innerTileWrappers[0]);
  }
  parentTileElement.removeChild(parentTileElement.firstElementChild);
  return tempDiv; /** DOM Elem */
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#outerTileWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#tileWrapper {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.tile {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="parentTileElement">
  <div class="tile">01</div>
  <div class="tile">02</div>
  <div class="tile">03</div>
  <div class="tile">04</div>
</div>

<input type="text" id="amountOfRows">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made this unnecessarily complicated. I'm not sure why you are using a constructor function here as the code uses functional styles in the most parts.

You could move the tiles to the wrapper element and then remove the inner wrappers in the `clearTiles` function. Now `organizeNumberOfRows` function can restart the process based on the new value.

Please note that the below snippet uses some of the ES2015 features that you can replace them with ES5 (arrow functions and a `let` keyword).

```
var parentTileElement = document.getElementById('parentTileElement'),
    amountOfRowsInput = document.getElementById('amountOfRows'),
    tiles = [].slice.call(parentTileElement.querySelectorAll('.tile'));

function NumberOfRows( /** Int */ defaultValue = 3) {
    this.set = function(val) {
        this.value = +val;
        clearTiles();
        organizeNumberOfRows(this.value);
    };
    this.get = function() {
        return this.value;
    }
    this.set(defaultValue);
}
var _numberOfRows = new NumberOfRows(3);

amountOfRows.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    _numberOfRows.set(this.value);
});

function organizeNumberOfRows( /** Int */ numberOfRows) {
    for (var i = 0, j = tiles.length; i < j; i += numberOfRows) {
       let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
       wrapper.className = 'innerWrapper';
       tiles.slice(i, i + numberOfRows).forEach(el => wrapper.appendChild(el) );
       parentTileElement.appendChild(wrapper);
    }
}

function clearTiles() {
    tiles.forEach(el => parentTileElement.appendChild(el) );
    [].forEach.call(parentTileElement.querySelectorAll('.innerWrapper'), el => {
        parentTileElement.removeChild(el);    
    });
}
```

Here is a updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zzn1s2sj/

If you are going to add many `{#,.}parentTileElement` element to the document then you should modify the code. The following code works for many wrapper elements.

```
// Some utility functions for querying the DOM
var findOne = sel => document.querySelector(sel);
var findMany = (sel, el) => {
  el = typeof el !== 'undefined' ? el : document;
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(el.querySelectorAll(sel)); 
}

function NumberOfRows(parentEl, chunkCount) {
    this.innerWrappers = []
    this.parent = parentEl;
    this.tiles = findMany('.tile', this.parent);
    this.chunkCount = chunkCount || 3;
    this.organize();
}
NumberOfRows.prototype.setChunk = function(val) {
   if ( +val < 1 || isNaN(+val) ) {
      throw new Error('The passed value should be a number more than 0, "' + val + '" given.');
   }
   this.chunkCount = +val;
   this.organize();
}

NumberOfRows.prototype.getChunk = function() {
   return this.chunkCount;
}

NumberOfRows.prototype.clearWrappers = function() {
    this.tiles.forEach(el => this.parent.appendChild(el) );
    this.innerWrappers.forEach( el => this.parent.removeChild(el) );
    this.innerWrappers = [];
}

NumberOfRows.prototype.organize = function() {
    this.clearWrappers();
    for (var i = 0, j = this.tiles.length; i < j; i += this.chunkCount) {
       let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
       wrapper.className = 'innerWrapper';
       this.tiles.slice(i, i + this.chunkCount).forEach(el => wrapper.appendChild(el) );
       this.parent.appendChild(wrapper);
       this.innerWrappers.push(wrapper);
    }
}

// Usage:
var _numberOfRows = new NumberOfRows(findOne('#parentTileElement'), 3);
findOne('#amountOfRows').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    _numberOfRows.setChunk(this.value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/12avgste/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried reading the docs on `call` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), but didn't quite understand it. Can you either explain it, or link a good and thorough tutorial of the point of it? Thanks!

Comment: @Jessica You are very welcome. Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265587/how-does-call-work-in-javascript. Please note that my second suggested code works for many elements. There is no need to modify it.